# How to upload images to Firebase from Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python-2.7, firebase, raspberry-pi, firebase-storage

I am having trouble uploading images to Firebase using Python. it would be great help if someone can provide a snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python), or [our docs on using GCS APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#apis) with Firebase Storage. From those docs:

```
# Import gcloud
from google.cloud import storage

# Enable Storage
client = storage.Client()

# Reference an existing bucket.
bucket = client.get_bucket('projectid.appspot.com')

# Upload a local file to a new file to be created in your bucket.
zebraBlob = bucket.get_blob('zebra.jpg')
zebraBlob.upload_from_filename(filename='/photos/zoo/zebra.jpg')

# Download a file from your bucket.
giraffeBlob = bucket.get_blob('giraffe.jpg')
giraffeBlob.download_as_string()
```